# How to drop the @Temp table used in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I am using cursor to pass the each employee wise information to do some calculation inside,

I have used some temp table with the declaration like

```
declare @tempTask1 table(emplid nvarchar(10), Values bigint)
```

and storing it into the main table

```
insert into Maintable
Select * from @tempTask1
```

but what happens is when the loop goes the `emplid` is kept on adding into the `@tempTask1` .

like example

```
E1 1001
E2 1002
...
```

as per the no of times the loop goes

so duplicate entry exists for each record and calculation failed.

How to drop this temp table and recreate the emp table used inside the loop to avoid these data problems.

Note: each loop shld take only unique emplid one time when it loops

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delete statement

```
DELETE @tempTask1
```

Comment: i have used deleting it. but again im getting two values both the E1 and E2 emplid..

Comment: Are you able to post more of your code?  It would be helpful to see what's happening inside the loop and where you're issuing the delete.